# Why does this array initialize behave differently?

Tags: ruby, arrays, initialization

I have

```
def initialize
  @board = [[0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0]] 
end
```

I thought I could shorten it to:

```
def initialize
  @board=[ [0] * 4] * 4
end
```

and they look the same, but only with the latter, I get an error like:

```
10) vertical turn can add 1 to an existing column of 2 with 1's at the ends                                             [20/18949]
   Failure/Error: expect([game.board[0][2], game.board[1][2], game.board[2][2], game.board[3][2]]).to eq [0,1,0,0]

     expected: [0, 1, 0, 0]
          got: [1, 1, 0, 1]

     (compared using ==)
   # ./spec/game_spec.rb:132:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this for your working and non-working code:

```
@board.map { |x| x.object_id }
```

and you will see the difference. The error is occurring because all the inner Arrays are the same object.

The problem is that

```
[ [0] * 4 ] * 4
```

is an Array which contains the *same* Array four times.

Whilst

```
[[0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

is an Array that contains four different Array objects.

When you `.inspect` them they look the same because Ruby doesn't show you the object ids.

Another way to implement your 0-ed Array might be:

```
Array.new(4) { Array.new(4) {0} }
```

Or, if you are dealing exclusively with 4x4 integers, you could take a look at the `narray` library, which does not have these kinds of issues, and is also very fast for bulk operations.